# Regex para limitar numero antes y después de la coma

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo un problema y es que estoy intentando limitar un campo numerico con expresión regular. De forma que solo pueda introducir un maximo de 6 numeros naturales y 3 decimales. Es decir

- 123456 = Correcto
- 1234567 = Incorrecto
- 123456,123 = Correcto

Sin embargo no consigo llegar a esa limitación. Lo más que he conseguido por mi cuenta es esto:

```
^(([0-9]{0,5})?(.[0-9]{0,2}))?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6drCrD_MFbe_Fr8h)

Comment: Prueba `^(([0-9]{0,6})?(\.[0-9]{0,3}))?$`

Comment: No me sirve @JDev no me da como valido por ejemplo 123

Comment: Cambia de sitio el `?` `(([0-9]{0,6})(\.[0-9]{0,3})?)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es necesario que uses los contenedores numéricos, puedes usar esta:

```
/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,3})?$/
```

`\d` te permite capturar dígitos (que es igual que expresar `[0-9]`) al menos 1 a 6 veces (`{1,6}`) desde el inicio de la línea (`^`). El caracter `?` te permite capturar entre 0 y 1 vez la expresión que se encuentra dentro del contenedor al que le sigue (`(\.\d{1,3})`).

Finalmente con `\.` capturas el punto literal seguido de al menos 1 a 3 dígitos (`\d{1,3}`), todo esto hasta el final de la línea (`$`).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y sobre todo por la explicación!. Va perfecto!